# How do I find out if a procedure or function exists in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do I find out if a procedure or function exists in a mysql database? and is there any discovery option? like a `show procedures;` (e.g. like `show tables;`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS
```

See [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/733349/310446).

Answer (score 30):

A generic answer to this type of question is that all MySQL databases include a database called [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) which includes all the metadata as tables you can just query.

The information you want is in a table called [ROUTINES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/routines-table.html).  For example:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE 
       ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE" 
   AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="dbname"
;
```

Comment: This also works in Oracle and SQL Server. I think its part of an ANSI standard

Comment: Be aware that this can be affected by permissions -- you will see the list of procedures that you have access to see.  This threw me off briefly when I got a partial list on one connection (using a more limited user name) and a different list on another connection.

Answer (score 1):

use the following function:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_exists_procedure;$$
CREATE FUNCTION f_exists_procedure(in_name VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS BIT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @f_result
    FROM information_schema.ROUTINES as info
    WHERE info.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND info.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND info.ROUTINE_NAME = in_name;

    RETURN @f_result;

END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is a bit overcomplicated, see Gaius's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spin Off of the answer from Gaius

```
SELECT IF( COUNT(*) = 0, 'F' , 'T' ) AS ProcedureExists
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'someDBName'
AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND UCASE(ROUTINE_NAME) = UCASE('someProcedureName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another latest way:

```
    SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure_name> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one specific procedure:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE `name` = 'value'
```